# Android wizard-like (step by step) application

Tags: android

I'd like to build an android step application so I can go back and forth between activities.

I'd like to create a base class for the step manager that includes two buttons to go forward and back, so in the child activities I don't have to recreate those controls every time. The step manager class has to take care of the switching between activities in a precise order and of passing data between them.

I tried to write some code but I can't merge the parent's layout with the child one!

`FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.frame);

LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(rId, fl, true);`

This code is in the parent class (inherited from Activity):

- the FrameLayout is the place holder for the child-layout controls;
- rId is the layout resource ID of a LinearLayout in the child xml layout.

I guess that the problem about that code is that I don't call the setContentView of the child layout, so anytime I use the findViewById of a child control I get a null pointer.

What is the best practice to create something like that?

Thanks, Simone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single activity thus avoiding passing data between them and saving memory.
In this activity you can use a *ViewSwitcher* or (better) a *ViewFlipper* to let the user navigate between steps.